# Opening a popup window in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript

I have this little script and this function. I need to open a popup window every 15 minutes, like a reminder. 
How can I put the target to be a popup window in the middle of the screen?

```
setTimeout(openUrl, 54000);
setInterval(openUrl, 54000);

function openUrl(){
   window.open('http://google.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the size of th opening window, if you do so, it'll be opening as a real popup

here's the code:

```
function openUrl(){
    window.open('http://google.com', 'test', 'height=100px;width=100px');

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thist is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Code is wrong. Format of the height and width are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` has properties for the size and location. Example:

```
window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'height=400,width=400,top=400,left=400');
```

[More Information](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)